# get review rating star by product id magento

Tags: magento-1.7, review, product-page

I need to show rating star on my page.

How to display rating star and review on my page ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get rating summary of product by below code:

```
    <?php echo $RatingOb=Mage::getModel('rating/rating')->getEntitySummary($_product->getId());
     $ratings=$RatingOb->getSum()/$RatingOb->getCount();
    ?>
    <?php if($ratings): ?>
    <div class="ratings">
        <div class="rating-box">
            <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $ratings; ?>%"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and  need to css and image in css file  / images file at Skin folder:

```
/* rating star */
.ratings { font-size:11px; line-height:1.25; margin:7px 0; }
.ratings strong { float:left; margin:1px 3px 0 0; }
.rating-box { width:69px; height:13px; font-size:0; line-height:0; background:url(../images/bkg_rating.gif) 0 0 repeat-x; text-indent:-999em; overflow:hidden; }
.rating-box .rating { float:left; height:13px; background:url(../images/bkg_rating.gif) 0 100% repeat-x; }
.ratings .rating-box { float:left; margin-right:3px; }
```

### Using Block call

```
<?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('review/helper')->getSummaryHtml($_product, 'short'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Also check review/helper/summary_short.phtml is default or change

Also you can product rating by

```
$_product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary()
```

Comment: can't get Star ,,,,,,  Output is 1 Review(s) | Add Your Review

Comment: cheeck again................

Comment: i got solution problem with css

i need review like this **Overall 4.9 out of 5 base on 89 customers**

Comment: @AmitBera i have different module that view the product details.Is there any idea to show the rating block on that page too?